Why there are a lot of "wallpaper sites" that don't get taken down?
These sites offer wallpapers for PCs, mobile devices, etc. They usually have a lot of copyrighted images in it. Is this caused because intellectual property holders don't care as these sites are offering value to fans of their works?

Copyright can only be enforced by the art owner.
Only the owner of a copyrighted item may enforce his copyright. Not the state, not a fan, the owner. And having someone file DMCA claims or lawsuits costs time and/or money. So deciding who to sue and who not is a monetary choice.
Some wallpapers are wanted to be out there
Some artwork is made availeable by the owner of a product as advertizement, and the proliferation to other sites is not just accepted as price of business, but wanted: the more the image proliferates, the more it does what it shall: advertize their product. That is free marketing.
